# Visual Studio 2015 screen size on iMac 21.5"

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio, windows-10, screen-resolution

How can I adjust the screen resolution on Visual Studio 2015 so that my windows forms can be built to scale and do not look like this (image below) when debugging?

I have Windows 10 running on iMac 21.5" 4k through OSx bootcamp, I believe it is the screen size that is messing things up.

[image]

Comment: Under VMWare Fusion on a Mac, you go into the VM > Settings > Display and turn off "use full resolution for Retina display. I'm not sure if there's an equivalent setting under Bootcamp.

Comment: Ensure you have VS2015 Update 1 installed.  Project > Add New Item > Application Manifest File.  Remove the comments around the dpiAware section.

Comment: I have VS2015 Update 1 installed. I cannot seem to locate the Application Manifest File when adding a new item? Form is in C++ if that changes anything?